# Download part of the youtube video in java android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to download part of the youtube video in java android?

Ex: out of 6 min length video, download only first 2 min or any time frame ?

we can use start and end params in this url https://www.youtube.com/embed/BmOpD46eZoA?start=28&amp;end=49 to play specific part of the video, in the same way is it possible to download some part of the video?

i am using this type of url for download **https://r1---sn-gwpa-itql.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1600242984...** but this will downloads entire video.

is there any query param to specify the range to download?
is there any other solution if query param not exists?